# Flask can't find user object

Tags: python, web-applications, flask, flask-login

I'm making a web app and I've got the following code (edited for brevity) that uses Flask-Login to handle logging in:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, logout_user, login_required

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).first()

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
        return user.first_name

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            email = request.form.get("email")
            user = User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()
            if user.is_correct_password(request.form.get("password")):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for("home"))
            else:
                return error("Login Failed")
        except:
            return error("Unable to log in.")

    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

However, I keep getting `NameError: global name 'user' is not defined`, even though I am sure that I have defined `user` because I am able to get through `@login_required`. (When I log out and try to go to the home page, I am told that I am unauthorized).

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue with your `home` view: `user` is not defined. I think you meant to use Flask-Login's `current_user`.

```
from flask_login import current_user

# ...

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
    return current_user.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

DON'T FOREGET TO IMPORT

> from flask_login import current_user

```
from flask_login import current_user
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route('/index', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def index():
   return render_template('index.html',user={"id":current_user.id, "name": current_user.name, "password":current_user.password})
```

AND ACCESS on TEMPLATE

```
    {% if user %}
    <h3>Greetings {{user}}</h3>
{% endif %}

      <table class="table table-striped" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
{% for key, value in user.items() %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```